# Proof of existence of chain map between singular chain complex of a product space and tensor product of singular chain complexes.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

[This question refers to a proof in the book "Topology and Geometry" by Bredon, p.316]
The Theorem is stated as follows:

> There exists a (…) chain map $\Theta:\Delta_*(X\times Y)\rightarrow \Delta_*(X)\otimes\Delta_*(Y)$ which is the canonical map $(x,y)\rightarrow x\otimes y$ in Degree $0$.

The proof is done by induction on the degree of the chain complexes. The case where we consider $0$-chains is clear by the assumption and it is stated there, that the case where $k=1$ is clear. But I don't know how to see this.
There is no information given about $\Theta$ in Degrees higher than $0$, so how should I convince myself that $\partial\Theta=\Theta\partial$ on chains of Degree $1$?
Formulated differently, suppose $(\sigma, \tau)\in \Delta_1(X\times Y)$, how to calculate $\partial\Theta (\sigma, \tau)?$

Comment: Isn't $\Theta$ constructed by induction precisely to get that it's a chain map ?

Comment: For higher degrees we construct $\Theta$ by induction such that everything works, and that's no problem for me.  But before starting the induction, it is stated that the case $k=1$ trivially holds.

Comment: Moreover, i think the case $k=1$ is not needed in the induction.  But still I'd be interested wether we can see it for this case (as it is stated) or if that's a typo?

Comment: Ok I just had a look at Bredon and you are right that it's not super clear. I think the proof that is given below works for $k=1$ (there's even a parenthetical statement starting with "If $k=1$, ..."); but you can even think of it that way : given $\sigma : \Delta^1\to X\times Y$, if you look at $\partial \sigma = (x_1,y_1)-(x_0,y_0)$, you get to $x_1\otimes y_1 - x_0\otimes y_0 = x_1\otimes (y_1-y_0) + (x_1-x_0)\otimes y_0 = \partial ( x_1\otimes (\pi_Y\circ \sigma) + (\pi_X\circ \sigma) \otimes y_0)$, so it works just as well